# Corrupt warning when trying to join in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Looking for some help with an error I have not seen before and can't seem to find any help around it here.

I am trying to join two datasets and then keep the non-duplicated entries. However, when I run the code below:

```
alllawsuits <- allfjccases %>% 
inner_join(.,allprisonsnos) %>%
distinct(CASENAME,PLT,DEF,FILEDATE,TERMDATE,NOSedit,Docket,completename,.keep_all=T)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Joining, by = c("Docket", "NOSedit", "File.Year", "File.Month", "File.Day")
Error: Internal error in ``date_validate()``: Corrupt ``Date`` with unknown type character.
```

The `Date` variable is not one of the merging variables and the code still does not run even if I exclude it from the two data frames. All the column types are the same across the two datasets and I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. Thoughts?

A couple other things: the code used to run fine in the past and `merge` works fine, just not any of the `join` functions from dplyr.

Comment: Please can you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your datasets?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is referencing some unspecified `tbl_df` variable that has with `Date` class but contains character data - this may be, but is not necessarily, the variable named `Date` (that seems to be how you are interpreting the error, and that is a reasonable but incorrect interpretation of the error).

This error is being thrown by `date_validate()`, an internal function in newer versions of the `vctrs` package, which is a dependency of `dplyr` and `tbl_df`. `vctrs` is more picky about what constitutes a valid `Date` object than most operations in base R. It doesn't matter whether the `Date` class variable is part of the join key because the column validation is performed when the new `tbl_df` object is created as a result of the join.

Normally a `Date` object is a numeric vector with the attribute `class = "Date"`. For some reason there is a special S3 method specifically for preventing `Date` objects from returning e.g. `is.numeric(my_date_object) = TRUE` (look at the definition of `base::is.numeric.Date()` - this method supersedes dispatch to the primitive `is.numeric` function for Date objects) but they ARE normally numeric values "under the hood", so to speak. If we strip off the class attribute we can verify this.

```
> test <- as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02"))
> test
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02"
> str(test)
 Date[1:2], format: "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02"
> is.character(test)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(test)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(unclass(test))
[1] TRUE
```

However, it is also possible to create a `Date` object by explicitly assigning the `Date` class to a `character` vector where all the individual elements are coercible to `numeric`. The resulting `Date` object prints as if it were a normal `Date` object but it is still a character vector.:

```
> test <- structure(c("21424", "21425"), class = "Date")
> test
[1] "2028-08-28" "2028-08-29"
> str(test)
 Date[1:2], format: "2028-08-28" "2028-08-29"
> is.character(test)
 TRUE
> is.numeric(test)
 FALSE
> is.numeric(unclass(test))
[1] FALSE
> tibble(a = test)
  Error: Internal error in `date_validate()`: Corrupt `Date` with unknown type character.
```

And there's your error. Somewhere upstream of the code that you have shown, you performed some operation that created a nonstandard `Date` column. Either don't do that, or coerce the offending column to a normal date with something like

```
blah blah blah... %>%
  mutate(my_column = as.Date(as.numeric(my_column), origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  left_join(blah blah ...
```

A lot of base R methods don't care about this because they perform implicit conversion before anything gets passed to a compiled function. `vctrs`, and `dplyr` verbs and joins by extension, do care about this. They achieve better performance by skipping implicit conversion for many operations. But as a tradeoff they have to be pickier about object types.

Comment: +1. This solved the issue - I didn't think an oddly formatted date would prevent a merge, but it did. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, the issue is not related to formatting. `format` in the context of R dates refers to how a date is printed to the console. The problem with your dates is that they have an unusual data type.